# Check if solution folder contains files that are not the part of the solution

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-extensions

How can I check if solution folder contains files that are not part of the solution? Is there any utility/extension that provides such functionality?
I want to find all junk files in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the user interface of Visual Studio:

You can click the Show All Files button on the toolbar of the Solution Explorer and it will show you with a kind of dimmed icon the files on disk that are not included in the project (you can right-click on them and you will find an Include In Project menu entry on the context menu).

Programmatically:

A solution is composed of projects and solution folders. In turn both the projects and solution folders can have files or subfolders. For details see my article [HOWTO: Navigate the files of a solution from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006004.aspx)

Using EnvDTE, a solution folder is modeled as an EnvDTE.Project (of kind EnvDTE80.ProjectKinds.vsProjectKindSolutionFolder). Notice that a solution folder can belong to the root solution (EnvDTE.Solution.Projects) or can belong to another solution folder (nested solution folder, EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems).

Once you have a project or solution folder modeled as an EnvDTE.Project, this interface has:

- An EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems collection with the files.
- Properties such as FullName, FileName and others in the Properties collection to get its full folder name on disk

So you can use System.IO to find the files in the folder full name that are not in the EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems collection.